# nmap + how to detected all machines IP's with range for example 10.64.*.*

Tags: linux, networking, nmap

How to verify the range of all machines with `nmap` within IP class

```
 10.64.*.*
```

For example we tried

```
nmap -sn 10.64.*.0/24 | grep redhat
```

in order to capture all machines with redhat name that have IPs from **10.64.1.0** to **10.64.255.255** but this doesn't work.

Comment: Is 10.64.*.* a connected network (i.e. the machine from which you're executing `nmap` has an IP in the same network)? Is the network subnetmask `255.255.0.0` (`/16`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *nmap* to scan `10.64.*.*` will take a lot of time as there are 4096 addresses to scan.
Also, for OS detection use `-O` option with nmap.
`-sn` only shows available host.
You can use `-v` to see the verbose output.

Comment: is it possible to find first the first three octat with nmap ?  ( for example in some cluster we have  10.64.30.xxx  and 19.64.31.xxx  ( is it possible to find it by nmap or other tool ?

Comment: If your ip is in the cluster you can check it by ifconfig utility.

Comment: but other machines could be with other octata

Comment: Ifconfig utility gives subnet mask. E.g. if my mask is 255.255.254.0 , as it has 23 1’s from beginning. So my ip range would be 10.64.0.0/23 . Try using the verbose output it will solve any doubts itself.

Comment: If you're forgoing the port scan, OS detection is likely to be significantly less reliable.  Also, you can speed things up further by adding `-PR` to use ARP to find hosts that are online and `-T4` to generally speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

Try for the target the syntax of `10.64.0.0/16` or `10.64.0-255.1-254`.

Comment: when I didi it then nmap stuck , ( we cant to cntrl C also )

Comment: I did it without the | grep , but I see nmap take a lot of time , and I must to get results ate least in one min

Comment: Try to add the `-T5` parameter to use the full available bandwidth, but may slow down the rest of the network.